Does Mark 10:15 give us a warning not to over-think/over-systematize theology?

Truly, I say to you, whoever does not receive the kingdom of God like a child shall not enter it.
(Mark 10:15, ESV)

Sometimes trying to rationalize what we don't understand approaches heresy.  Note heresy comes from αἵρεσις, which is translated factions in 1 Cor. 11:19, and party in Acts for Sadducees and Pharoses (5:17; 15:5; 26:5) as well as Christians called a sect (24:5,14; 28:22).
P.S. It seems that overthinking theology is what interfered with Pharoses and Sadducees receiving Christ even though they saw the miraculous signs Jesus performed.

The answer to this question is actually in the verse quoted by the OP -

Mark 10:15 - Truly I say to you, whoever shall not receive the kingdom
of God as a child shall never enter into it."

Note that this says nothing about systematized theology but is talking about the reception, by the individual, of the citizenship of the Kingdom of God.  There are many others that discuss this important idea -

Luke 8:13 - The seeds on rocky ground are those who hear the word and receive it with joy, but they have no root. They believe for a season, but in the time of testing, they fall away.
Acts 8:14 - When the apostles in Jerusalem heard that Samaria had received the word of God, they sent Peter and John to them.
Acts 11;1 - The apostles and brothers throughout Judea soon heard that the Gentiles also had received the word of God.
Acts 17:11 - Now the Bereans were more noble-minded than the Thessalonians, for they received the message with great eagerness and examined the Scriptures every day to see if these teachings were true.
2 Thess 2:10 - and in every deception of wickedness unto those perishing, in return for which they did not receive the love of the truth in order for them to be saved.

The reception of the Word and the kingdom of God should be done with the simplicity of child without extinguishing the detail and maturity that comes with growing understanding.

+1 great answer Dottard. I would also add Ephesians 1:13 to your list, which says, "In him you also, when you heard the word of truth, the gospel of your salvation, and believed in him, were sealed with the promised Holy Spirit".

There's also the aspect that unlike a child, when presented with a new idea most adults will interpret it in terms of what they already know, making the concept fit into their world view rather than allowing their world view to change to fit the new concept.

@RayButterworth - excellent point.

Before anyone can receive, first their hands must be empty in order to accept. It's not a head-trip but a heart transplant, spiritually speaking.

“Truly, I say to you, whoever does not receive the kingdom of God like a child shall not enter it,”
This is a call for simplicity and humility in faith.

To receive the kingdom of God “as a little child,” is to receive it
after the manner of a child, with simplicity and faith, humility and
love. - (Ellicott's Commentary)


It means that those most eligible to experience God's glory and
sovereignty in their lives are the people who have no presumption that
they legally or spiritually deserve it. - (bibleref)


As a little child - With the temper and spirit of a child - teachable,
mild, humble, and free from prejudice and obstinacy. - (Barnes' Notes)

The verse is suggesting that the kingdom of God must be received with the openness, trust, and the innocence characteristic of a child. This is not necessarily a warning against theological thought or systematization per se, but rather, it's a caution against attitudes that can accompany such processes, like pride, self-reliance, and the loss of wonder and dependence on God.

We need to approach Him with a heart of trust and dependence, just as
a child trusts and depends on their parent.
We must let go of our pride, doubts, and self-sufficiency, and
surrender our lives completely to God. - (dailyeffectiveprayer)

Theological systematization has been a part of Christian tradition for centuries, aiming to understand and articulate faith coherently. Figures like Peter Lombard and John Wesley have contributed significantly to the systematization of theology, each in their own time. However, the concern you’ve raised about over-systematization is totally valid, in the sense that it can lead to an over-reliance on human reasoning and a departure from the core tenets trying to be communicated of faith, trust, dependence, and humility before God.
So in Mark 10:15, the emphasis on childlike faith serves as a reminder to maintain the essence of faith, which is a personal and trusting relationship with God, rather than merely an intellectual assent to a set of doctrines. However might I add a quote:
‘What strikes me today is the incomplete and fragmentary character of our faith: the lack of precision in our Christian conceptions; a certain ignorance of the wonderful things which God has done for us and which he has revealed to us for the salvation and nourishment of our souls. I discover the traces of this ignorance in our preaching as well as in our daily life. And here is one of the causes of the feebleness of spiritual life in the bosom of our flocks and among ourselves. To these fluid Christian convictions, there necessarily corresponds a lowered Christian life.’ (Revue théologique de Montauban, 13e Année, p. 14.)
Theology, for what it is, should seek to understand the divine.

The word “theology” comes from two Greek words that combined mean “the
study of God.” Christian theology is simply an attempt to understand
God as He is revealed in the Bible. - (gotquestions)


from Koine Greek θεολογία (theología), from θεολόγος (theológos,
adjective), from θεός (theós) + λόγος (lógos). By surface analysis,
theo- +‎ -logy. - (wiktionary)

To conclude, Mark 10:15 reminds us believers to approach God with the heart of a child, full of faith, trust, and without the pretense that often comes with adulthood. Therefore, for believers, it should be encouraged to balance their intellectual pursuits with the spiritual posture of humility and dependence on God’s grace.

You say: "the concern you’ve raised about over-systematization is totally valid, in the sense that it can lead to an over-reliance on human reasoning..." There are many doctors and professors whose Christianity seems to be an intellectual exercise rather than a transformation of the heart that results in "humility and dependence on God's grace."  Well said.
